# Random selection Daml

Tags: random, daml

Does anyone know how to simulate a random selection in Daml? My understanding is that I cannot make non-deterministic choices in Daml (I should call an external Oracle and ask for an index), but for testing purposes I should be able to simulate a random selection within the software.

Is that correct? Could someone please help?
I cannot find any function such as "choose" "shuffle" or any other related function.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Any help would be very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the outcome of interpreting Daml need to be deterministic. Daml is supposed to encode the rules of the game (which need to yield deterministic results for all the players), while code using the Ledger API defines the strategy used, which can introduce an element of randomness to it. If you want to introduce some level of randomness to your workflow, you will need to make it part of the interaction with an off-ledger component.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on this? Can you give me some more details? As I don't have technical background is quite difficult for me to understand how to implement this. Any more info would be extremely appreciated!!

Comment: If you want to introduce randomness, you will need to write a piece of logic that interacts with Daml using the Ledger API, rather than using Daml. https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api.html